# liquibase - How to return output into placeholder variables from executeCommand

Tags: liquibase

is it possible to run the executeCommand and receive a return parameter back?

I am essentially trying to either call a url that returns json, run a .bat or run an sql select query and feed the output/print out results into placeholder variables of following changesets.

Are there any other tags that achieve this if executeCommand does not cover it?

Thanks

Toby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've quickly checked 
https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/9ae7f90a0bbbbcec229a0788afa74831db348ced/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/change/core/ExecuteShellCommandChange.java
and looks like now it just compares return code with 0 and nothing is returned.
Maybe you should implement your own custom change (http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/custom_change.html) and set some variable there.